# Javascript Regex to match 0 to 6 length number in every new line (It is used to match text in a textarea)

Tags: javascript, regex

For example -
Text area with these two lines then it is matched

```
122344 
122345
```

Textarea with below two lines is not matched

```
122333333 // more than 6 digits
233444
```

tried this regex - `^[0-9]{0,6}\n$` but not working

Comment: Should there be a match in the second exampole for 233444 ? How are you using the code? Note that you are matching a mandatory newline.

Comment: How are you using that regex in your code? What's your HTML? We need enough code, and information, to reproduce your problem without having to guess.

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to validate if all lines contain only 6 digit numbers (true/false result), or return a list of all 6 digit numbers (ignore others) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it without the newline (`\n`) character. Just use the global and multiline flags.

```js
str = `122333333
233444
123456`;
let found = str.match(/^[0-9]{0,6}$/gm);

console.log(found);
```

If you want the first 6 nummers of the longer number too remove the end line character too (`$`).

```js
str = `122333333
233444
123456`;
let found = str.match(/^[0-9]{0,6}/gm);

console.log(found);
```